# Multi-user database for desktop application

Tags: c#, wpf, database

I am developing a multi user, windows database application using WPF. I have following questions:

1. I will be developing only the client software and the user depending on their needs should be able to connect to database they want (they may have any database already running in their organisation). In the sense, in client software they should be able to configure the database they want to connect to.

   What is the best approach??
2. Should I be using ADO.Net or there are any other approaches?
3. What if the user want to store the data in the cloud?

I am a hobby developer and my understanding is very primitive.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: The way this is worded is a little off topic for SO, as it's about application design as opposed to specific implementation, but I'll try and give you some hints...1. You might use a drop down box if you knowingly have a list of potential databases that they might be connecting to, else this can maybe be a text box.  2. ADO.NET is probably the most common approach, however there's a few other ways this can be done...3. I don't have any experience in this area, so I'm not too sure how to go about this.

Comment: Such requirements are acceptable for 'expensive' applications. In small/medium projects, open-ended requirements KILL the project. . There are many DBMS types out there. Do you think you can support them all? What about different versions of those databases? Don't be afraid to educate your customer and tell them to narrow the scope. Not only because of development but also for the sake of testing.

Comment: I think u have hit it it on the head Emmad. It has sort of become open ended. But do u think it is difficult to implement it? Atleast can we support few major DB? Here the actual problem is application may be used by a small company which may not be interested in statistical data analysis and they may store it in local PC(I am thinking abt XML file here). On other hand it may be used by bigger organisations who may be interested in doing data analysis. What is the best approach here?? Thanks for your time??

Comment: @indra Please sign my answer (at the bottom, the only answer here) as your question's answer if it's answered your question, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [WPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) is a cutting edge technology created by Microsoft.
   I very recommend using this technology, despite, if you're searching for something more simple less complicated, you can develop it by [WinForm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) which, also, created by Microsoft (obsoleted technology).
2. There are many frameworks which give you a comfortable way to connect your database. Among them, you can find: [Entity Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_Framework) (by Microsoft) or [NHibernate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate). These technologies are called ORM which gives you the ability to access your database by access an object (instance) in your code which demonstrates your db tables by an object.
   You have, almost, nothing to do straight with your db once you configured your ORM framework properly.
   From my experience, and since you a hobby developer (as you mentioned), I would recommend you not to use these frameworks. If you're not in a series company with specialized developers, it can drives you crazy when something goes wrong. I, personally, use ADO.NET and access the db straight by that.
3. If the users want to save the data in the cloud you can just save it there. It must be using database there, in the cloud. Don't let the name 'cloud' to confuse you. The cloud you're going to use may contains some database, use it like you do with every database. Unless you want to authenticate your users against the special cloud service they currently use. Then you just learn how this cloud works with it's individual services. I can tell that if you're going to use [Azure cloud service](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cloud-services/) (for example), you can use their [ADAL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj573266.aspx) API (with C# code) to authenticate users. Each cloud and it's own authentication services.

I hope it will be useful for you.